# Flutter Pub Get Error when trying to run some old project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Evening All,

I am was trying to run some old project in github but when trying to run pub get having this kind of error

```
Running "flutter pub get" in budgex...                          
Because flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 depends on html >=0.15.0 <1.0.0 and every version of link_previewer depends on html ^0.14.0+2, flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 is incompatible with link_previewer.
So, because budgex depends on both link_previewer ^1.2.1 and flutter_html ^2.2.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because budgex depends on both link_previewer ^1.2.1 and flutter_html ^2.2.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

i am already change some dependencies into latest version without local package folder and files from plugin here is the pubspec.yaml

```
name: budgex
description: This Application is a Simple Budget Manager

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  bitbox : ^0.0.5
  flutter_icons : ^1.1.0
  link_previewer : ^1.2.1
  web3dart : ^2.5.1
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^0.2.1
  animations: ^1.1.2
  badges: ^2.0.1
  beamer: ^0.14.1
  bitcoin_flutter: ^2.0.2
  bot_toast: ^3.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.0.0
  chart_sparkline: ^1.0.5
  charts_flutter: ^0.6.0
  container_tab_indicator: ^0.3.0
  csv: ^4.0.3
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dartx: ^0.7.1
  dartz: ^0.10.0-nullsafety.2
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  decimal: ^1.2.0
  encrypt: ^5.0.0
  english_words: ^3.1.0
  extended_image: ^4.1.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.3
  fl_chart: ^0.36.2
  flash: ^1.5.1
  flex_color_picker: ^2.1.1
  flutter_barcode_sdk: ^1.2.2
  flutter_bloc: ^7.0.0
  flutter_dynamic_icon: ^2.0.0
  flutter_echarts: ^2.1.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^6.0.1
  flutter_html: ^2.2.1
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^4.0.3
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^0.1.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  flutter_uix: ^0.1.2-nullsafety.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  formz: ^0.4.0
  freezed_annotation: ^0.14.2
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  grouped_list: ^4.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^0.14.0+4
  http_auth: ^0.2.5
  json_diff: ^0.2.0
  keccak: ^1.0.3
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
  liquid_pull_to_refresh: ^3.0.0
  local_auth: ^1.1.6
  logger: ^1.0.0
  marquee: ^2.2.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5345
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.0
  money_formatter: ^0.0.3
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.0.0
  overlay_support: ^1.2.0
  package_info: 2.0.0
  page_transition: ^1.0.9
  path: ^1.6.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.7+2
  permission_handler: ^8.1.2
  pinput: ^1.2.0
  pretty_qr_code: ^2.0.2
  protobuf: ^2.0.0
  protoc_plugin: ^20.0.0
  qr: ^2.1.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  random_string: ^2.0.1
  readmore: ^1.0.1
  riverbloc: ^0.5.0
  rounded_loading_button: ^2.0.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  shimmer: ^1.0.1
  showcaseview: ^0.1.6
  sticky_headers: ^0.1.8
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.2.44+1
  table_calendar: ^3.0.1
  theme_provider: ^0.5.0
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  ultimate_data_generator : ^1.0.0
  validators: ^2.0.0+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc_test: ^8.0.2
  build_runner: ^2.0.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.9
  freezed: ^0.14.2
  hive_generator: ^1.1.0
  json_serializable: ^4.1.3
  mockito: ^5.0.10

dependency_overrides:
  args: ^2.1.1
  crypto: ^3.0.0
  hex: ^0.1.2
  convert: ^3.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  bip39: ^1.0.5
  pointycastle: ^3.0.0
  dart_style: ^2.0.0
  http: ^0.13.0
  fixnum: ^1.0.0
  vin_decoder : ^0.1.4+1
  basic_utils : 3.3.3

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: assets/icon/icon.png

flutter_native_splash:
  image: assets/images/splash.png
  color: "121212"
  android_disable_fullscreen: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  # shed hill people icon fragile critic vicious return write coconut jump clutch
  # royal calm banner faith tiny capital tooth nerve attract addict garbage wish
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/rive/
    - assets/icon/
    - fonts/

  fonts:
    - family: Avenir Next
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/AvenirNext.otf
    - family: WorkSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/WorkSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    # - family: Roboto
    #   fonts:
    #     - asset: fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
    #     - asset: fonts/Roboto-normal.ttf
```

Anyone can help this problem? appreciated it for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to solve above problem is, rather than specifying version code beside of any package you can just do below thing

```
flutter_html: 
link_previewer: 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to update your dependencies so that they are compatible with each other. You can do this by modifying the version constraints in your pubspec.yaml file. For example, if you change the version constraint for html in link_previewer to be compatible with the constraint in flutter_html, you should be able to run `flutter pub get`

It is also possible that a newer version of link_previewer or flutter_html may have been released that resolves this conflict, so you may want to check for updates to these packages. However, be sure to carefully review the changelog for any updates to make sure that they won't break your project.

This error indicates that there is a conflict between the versions of `link_previewer` and `flutter_html`